# Rectangular volume of interest structural MRI for SPM/Matlab Image processing

Tags: matlab, roi

I am using matlab/spm to create a volume of interest in the brain (analyze format).  I know the following...

- shape of volume (rectangle)
- size of volume
- center voxel

I have used the marsbar toolbox to create a volume of interest given the above parameters and it works great.  My only problem is the volume of interest needs a slight rotation/tilt in sagittal view in order to be parallel to the corpus callosum.  Marsbar only allows the image to be presented horizontally and does not allow for any manual tilting.

Just wondering if anyone knows of any solutions to this or useful toolboxes/ programs?  I've had a look and not been able to find anything that can create a rectangular voxel of interest.

Thanks,

Jennifer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the Check Reg option in SPM you can adjust the orientation of the image and apply it.